# Jquery $.post html to external php and print the html as pdf. Need to find optimal solution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I get mysql data.

Create - echo the mysql data as html.

If visitor wants to print the data as pdf (i mean to create pdf file and save on computer), i with jquery take the data and send to external php file. In the external php file, using `http://www.tcpdf.org` solution i want to create pdf file (on fly, only as variable; i do not want to save the file on my server) so that user can save it.

User remains on the same url, just after user clicks button, i offer the user to save rendered pdf. I do not want to change url or add html content to the url (like `print_pdf.php?html_content`).

At the moment i use code like below.

```
<div id="to_print_as_pdf">
<div>Some content from mysql</div>
<table>Another content from mysql</table>
</div>

<button type="button">Click to print as pdf</button>
<span id="result_print_pdf"></span>
```

Jquery to send the data

```
<script>

$("button").click(function(){ 

$.post('_prepare_to_print_pdf.php', 
{ content_to_print: $('#to_print_as_pdf').html() }, 
function(result_print_pdf) { 
$('#result_print_pdf').html(result_print_pdf).css('color', 'black');
});

}); 

</script>
```

File `_prepare_to_print_pdf.php`

```
$_SESSION['content_to_print'] = trim($_POST['content_to_print']);

<script> 
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/_print_pdf.php";
</script>
```

File `_print_pdf.php`

```
//Use http://www.tcpdf.org solution
$html = $_SESSION['content_to_print'];
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

How to do the same without `_prepare_to_print_pdf.php`? Above solution waste server resources (creating session).

I tried with `$.post` to send html content directly to `_print_pdf.php`, but in such case instead of prompting to to save pdf file, i see "garbage" characters...

**Solution at the moment**

May be will help to someone

```
$('#for_hidden_form_for_print_pdf').append('<form action="_print_pdf.php" method="post" target="_blank" id="hidden_form_for_print_pdf">' + 
'<textarea id="content_to_print" name="content_to_print">html content to send </textarea>' + 
'<div><button style="display: none;" id="btn_to_print_pdf">Print pdf</button></div></form>');

$('#btn_to_print_pdf').trigger('click');

$( "#hidden_form_for_print_pdf" ).remove();
```

So when visitor clicks button/icon, i take necessary html data, insert into `textarea id="content_to_print"`. Then trigger click for `btn_to_print_pdf`, then remove appended form. So i send to external php file, necessary html code. In php file i process the html code, create content for pdf file and print.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I read it... but...not sure. Code looks differently and as i understand code takes existing file. But if no simple solution, then again will go through the answer. And seems if the answer will not help, then will use the existing solution.

Comment: "Code looks differently" Yes, it is using the native [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of jQuery's `$.ajax`

Comment: Another option would be to add a form to your HTML that just has a hidden input (and nothing else) and an action of "_print_pdf.php" and method of "post".  On click of the button, populate the value of the hidden input with the desired text and trigger a form submit.  That will allow you to use `$_POST['content_to_print']` instead of `$_SESSION['content_to_print']`.

Comment: Thanks, at the moment decided to use your solution.